# How to generate resource files from parent POM in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I want to have parent POM similar to the following:

```
<project>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.whatever</groupId>
    <artifactId>whatever-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- plugin for generating resource files -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>...</groupId>
                <artifactId>...</artifactId>
                <version>...</version>
                <configuration>
                    <files>
                        <file>
                            <!-- location relative to jar's root -->
                            <location>lorem.txt</location>
                            <!-- file contents -->
                            <contents>Lorem ipsum dolor</contents>
                        </file>
                    </files>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>...</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

So when it will be used as parent POM then `lorem.txt` file will be automatically generated and packaged inside jar.

Comment: Parent POM merges with child POM so if you do something like that for your child and move relavant part to parent, it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need a file include inside your jar/zip file.
   Please refer the way to use maven assembly plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-assembly-plugin-2.6/examples/index.html

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

EX:

```
<assembly xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
  <id>bin</id>

  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <fileSets>

    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/main/config_templates</directory>
      <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
      <outputDirectory>config_templates</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>dep/*</include>
        <include>classpaths/*</include>
        <include>endorsed/*</include>
        <include>*.jar</include>
      </includes>
      <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
```

2. If you need the structure of your project from the first time, please refer the way to create proj from your own archetype:

https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html

I hope they can help you.